# Unable to save property with value that looks like a date in Azure Cosmos DB Graph (Gremlin)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to save a property value that looks similar to a date, or part of a date, that gives me an error in Azure Cosmos DB with Graph API (Gremlin) like the following:

```
g.V('id').property('PartReference', '2016-02');
```

The error message

```
Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Data type 'Date' not yet supported by
Binary Comparison functions
```

To me it seems like Gremlin or Cosmos DB is trying to guess the datatype and get it wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how you are executing the query? Is this via Portal, Microsoft.Azure.Graphs or using a gremlin driver client?

Comment: I'm using the .NET SDK from Nuget

Comment: CosmosDB most definitely tries to do something funky with dates. I like to save my dates as ISO strings because they are sortable, but CosmosDB always changes my date string to some US kinda format: `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` cc @OliverTowers

Comment: @DejanJanjušević same problem here. Have you found a way to have dates correctly set?

Comment: @LionelD I haven't found a way. Instead, I used a workaround where I saved dates as strings prepended by "#" character. When saving the DateTime type, I prepend that character and when parsing DateTime value from the database, I parse the string without that character. But the solution with ticks below seems better.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, Azure's graph API cares only about three types of data: bool, string and number. At the route of it, you should be able to convert any complex or contextual data into it's primitive representation and by-pass this delight of theirs...

For date and time data, I have settled for using **ticks**, which can be saved as a **number** which is filterable

Comment: I agree. Use the UnixDateTimeConverter class to do this easily. On your DateTime property add the following attribute: [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))] it shoulld do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that it only cares about bool, string and number as it is obviously trying to process a date string as a date. I have hit this problem where I have serialised to ISO and got back a US format with only seconds.

I do agree that the work around for now is to use ticks, I have switched to ticks, and hope when this problem is solved I can reprocess the data and go back to ISO format.

I have not tried the gremlin.net api, this might handle dates consistently.